# No module named 'tensorflow' error showing up in Windows 10 Python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10

I installed Tensorflow using the instructions on its website https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip. I used the virtual environment option, but didn't use Anaconda.
Everything went smoothly until I tried to import tensorflow in python. I did 
    `import tensorflow as tf`
in my Python file and in return I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

What's up with this? How can I fix it? I'm using Python 3.6 on a Windows 10 machine. All other answers to this I could find involved Anaconda which I didn't use. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use the same `virtualenv` for running the file?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start using Anaconda. It just makes life so much easier (especially when handling different Versions of TensorFlow)

Make sure that you are *in* the Environment you‘ve installed it. Note that you need to activate it first (as shown on the Installation tutorial).

Another thing you can try is installing it with `pip3`. Although this didn‘t always work for me (it can lead to trouble when having python 3.7 installed)

Lastly you could lookup which python is linked in the PATH and verify that the tensorflof packages are actually there.